# Best way to throttle outgoing requests in C# by time and some extra criteria?

Tags: c#, http, concurrency, throttling, rate

I have to call an external HTTP API that only allows one request every 4 seconds by userId. As long as I'm calling this API sending a different userId each time, I can call it at any rate.

In this code I'm able to comply with the external API rate, but I'm not doing it in the optimal way, since some requests get blocked by previous calls even if that userId doesn't need to wait. (Check comments in code)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var caller = new ExternalAPICaller();

            caller.RunCalls();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class ExternalAPICaller
    {
        private static SemaphoreSlim throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(20); // up to 20 concurrent calls

        private static List<string> userIds = new List<string>();

        private const int rateLimitByUser = 4000;

        public async Task CallAPIWithThrottling(string userId)
        {
            if (userIds.Contains(userId)) Thread.Sleep(rateLimitByUser);

            userIds.Add(userId);

            await throttler.WaitAsync();

            var task = MockHttpCall(userId);

            _ = task.ContinueWith(async s =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(rateLimitByUser);
                throttler.Release();
                userIds.Remove(userId);
            });
        }

        public Task MockHttpCall(string id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("http call for " + id);
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task RunCalls()
        {
            await CallAPIWithThrottling("Mike");
            await CallAPIWithThrottling("John");
            await CallAPIWithThrottling("Sarah");
            await CallAPIWithThrottling("Matt");

            await CallAPIWithThrottling("John");
            await CallAPIWithThrottling("Jacob"); // this should be called right away, but the second John makes it wait

            await CallAPIWithThrottling("John");
            await CallAPIWithThrottling("Amy"); // this should be called right away, but the thrid John makes it wait
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many userid's are you expecting to use with this, a limited small amount endlessly repeated, or an endless/large amount (making them up on the spot)

Comment: I expect to process large amounts in a short period of time, since this logic is part of a batch job.

Comment: So you got two limits: 1/userID/4seconds plus a total connection limit, wich might be variable as the load changes. Now the ideal solution would be to *ask the Service holder to give you some way to bulk retreive data*. With that much work put into limitations, I would asume he has a rule against Automated processing of his service. So this action could get you in **very** hot legal water. And it is not like he would not notice the sudden spike in requests that such an autoamtion would bring with it.

Comment: I think *RX* would probably suit this, it has throttling, supports async, and max parallel limit, probably mixed with some sort of Dictionary/ConcurrentDictionary to manage the user ids and observables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to abstract the throttling functionality, so that I can test it independently. I would make a `Throttler` class that can be configured with global and per-user concurrency limits and delays. In your case the configuration would be:

- Global concurrency limit: **20**
- Global delay: **0** (simultaneous requests for different users are allowed)
- Per user concurrency limit: **1**
- Per user delay: **4000**

Here is an implementation of the `Throttler` class. The per user concurrency limit is omitted for simplicity (it would require a second `SemaphoreSlim` per user).

```
public class Throttler<TKey>
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _globalConcurrencySemaphore;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _globalDelaySemaphore;
    private readonly int _globalDelay;
    private readonly int _perKeyDelay;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, SemaphoreSlim> _perKeyDelaySemaphores;

    public Throttler(int globalConcurrencyLimit, int globalDelay, int perKeyDelay)
    {
        _globalConcurrencySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(globalConcurrencyLimit,
             globalConcurrencyLimit);
        _globalDelaySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
        _globalDelay = globalDelay;
        _perKeyDelay = perKeyDelay;
        _perKeyDelaySemaphores = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, SemaphoreSlim>();
    }

    public async Task<TResult> Execute<TResult>(TKey key,
        Func<Task<TResult>> taskFactory)
    {
        var perKeyDelaySemaphore = _perKeyDelaySemaphores.GetOrAdd(
            key, _ => new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));
        await perKeyDelaySemaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        ReleaseAsync(perKeyDelaySemaphore, _perKeyDelay);
        await _globalDelaySemaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        ReleaseAsync(_globalDelaySemaphore, _globalDelay);
        await _globalConcurrencySemaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        try
        {
            var task = taskFactory();
            return await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        finally
        {
            _globalConcurrencySemaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    private async void ReleaseAsync(SemaphoreSlim semaphore, int delay)
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay).ConfigureAwait(false);
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

The delay is between one semaphore acquirement and the next. The delay of the HTTP call is not taken into account.

Usage example:

```
var throttler = new Throttler<string>(20, 0, 4000);
var keys = new string[] { "Mike", "John", "Sarah", "Matt", "John", "Jacob",
    "John", "Amy" };
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var key in keys)
{
    tasks.Add(throttler.Execute(key, () => MockHttpCall(key)));
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

async Task<int> MockHttpCall(string id)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} HTTP call for " + id);
    await Task.Delay(300);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```xml
11:20:41.635 HTTP call for Mike
11:20:41.652 HTTP call for John
11:20:41.652 HTTP call for Sarah
11:20:41.652 HTTP call for Matt
11:20:41.653 HTTP call for Jacob
11:20:41.654 HTTP call for Amy
11:20:45.965 HTTP call for John
11:20:50.272 HTTP call for John
```

Comment: I figured out that one semaphore cannot handle both the delay and the concurrency, so I updated the implementation. Now there are 2 global semaphores.

Comment: Nice answer uovote , be aware though semaphoreSlim is based on a spin lock, and not suited for anything other than extremely short synchronisation tasks, ahh sorry edit, you are calling waitasnc, which doesnt, carry on :)